# average,sort from high to low-format number

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

found the following xsl/xml question need assistance in answering it.take it as a challenge.
The question: 
1-get the average per continents in(format-number"###,###.00"),
2-total per batch and should be sorted from highest to lowest,
3-top expensive batch just list
have tried to get some templates (below) please help with coming up with a template which will run to yield the required results
Total batch (highest to lowest)=
average per continent=###.00 =                                                                                                        top three of expensive batch=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="factory.xslt"?>

 <factory>
    <branch>
        <continent>North America</continent>
        <location>usa</location>
        <address>671 fourth avenue</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>toyota</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>12000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>opel</name>
                <number_of_makes>5</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>10000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Europe</continent>
        <location>france</location>
        <address>671 paris</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>nissan</name>
                <number_of_makes>10</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>20000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>North America</continent>
        <location>detroit</location>
        <address>45 parklane</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>doge</name>
                <number_of_makes>40</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>35000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>cadillac</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>14000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Europe</continent>
        <location>germany</location>
        <address>675 berlin avenue</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>opel</name>
                <number_of_makes>42</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>19000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>mercedes</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>24000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>North America</continent>
        <location>texas</location>
        <address>46 parkland way</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>hummer</name>
                <number_of_makes>30</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>45000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>cadillac</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>14000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Asia</continent>
        <location>india</location>
        <address>67 new delhi way</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>tata</name>
                <number_of_makes>12</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>25000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>ford</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>20000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Asia</continent>
        <location>japan</location>
        <address>56 yorki avenue</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>mazda</name>
                <number_of_makes>40</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>23000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>hyundai</name>
                <number_of_makes>20</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>10000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Asia</continent>
        <location>korea</location>
        <address>12 yung </address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>skyline</name>
                <number_of_makes>14</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>18000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>toyota</name>
                <number_of_makes>40</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>12000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <continent>Europe</continent>
        <location>england</location>
        <address>56 parklane</address>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>bentely</name>
                <number_of_makes>24</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>50000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
        <batch>
            <car_make>
                <name>ferrari</name>
                <number_of_makes>10</number_of_makes>
                <price_per_make>120000</price_per_make>
            </car_make>
        </batch>
    </branch>
</factory>
```

the following is xslt version 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  TOTAL BATCH:-<a>
    $<xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
      <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="/*/*/*/batch"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="'number_of_make'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="'price_per_make'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </a><br/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="sumProducts">

  <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
  <xsl:param name="pName1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pName2"/>
  <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() >1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="$pName1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="$pName2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1] * $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TotalPrice">

  <xsl:param name="pList"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRunningTotal" select="0"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pList">
      <xsl:variable name="varMapPath" select="$pList[1]"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="TotalPrice">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pRunningTotal"
         select="$pRunningTotal + $varMapPath/productpriceperunit * $varMapPath/productsordered"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pRunningTotal"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the exact wanted output.

Comment: There are many errors and the XSLT isn't even well-formed XML document. More importantly, the source XML document has nested batches -- I think this is an error that must be corrected. Please, edit the question and correct these errors.

Comment: dimitre,the xml document is just fine ,..yea the xslt is what i tried coming up with,..have tried to emphasize the question in deep,..if you can you can generate your version so long as it produces the end resuld which are average per continent,total per batch per continent in highest to lowest and finally top three batches which are expensive,.

Comment: troy, No, I guess there shouldn't be *nested* batches -- but the provided XML document contains one instance of nested batches -- around line 75.

Comment: branch>>>>>(batch>>>>car_make) X2..from the we got two batches under a branch per continent,one continent should have 2 batches,..so the xml is just the exact way i found the question,..whats your view

Comment: Why for Texas 46 parkland way there is a batch *inside* of another batch? If this is possible and OK you *must* explain this in the question -- this is very difficult to spot visually.

Comment: one continent should have 2 batches,..so the xml is just the exact way i found the question,..whats your view –

Comment: dimitre,.have changed it,..thanks for that,.not easy to spot,.

Comment: I answerd this -- the first part. Please, split this into three questions -- not fair to aggregate three questions into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

<xsl:variable name="title">Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="html">
    <xsl:element name="head">
      <xsl:element name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="body">
      <xsl:element name="h1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:call-template name="AverageCarPricePerContinent" />
      <xsl:call-template name="TotalPerBatch" />
      <xsl:call-template name="TopNMostExpensiveBatches"><xsl:with-param name="n" select="3" /></xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/factory/branch">
  <xsl:call-template name="ContinentAverage">
    <xsl:with-param name="continentName" select="./continent/text()" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="AverageCarPricePerContinent">
  <xsl:element name="h2">
    <xsl:text>1. Average Car Price Per Continent</xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="ol">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/factory/branch[not(./continent=preceding-sibling::branch/continent)]" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TotalPerBatch">
  <xsl:element name="h2">
    <xsl:text>2. Total Per Batch (&#x25bc;)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:call-template name="OutputBatchesDesc">
    <xsl:with-param name="batches" select="/factory/branch/batch" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TopNMostExpensiveBatches">
  <xsl:param name="n" />
  <xsl:element name="h2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('3. Top ',$n,' Most Expensive Batch(es)')"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:call-template name="OutputBatchesDesc">
    <xsl:with-param name="batches" select="/factory/branch/batch" />
    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="OutputBatchesDesc">
  <xsl:param name="batches" />
  <xsl:param name="n" select="count($batches)" />
  <xsl:element name="ol">
    <xsl:for-each select="$batches">

      <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="(./car_make/price_per_make)[1] * (./car_make[1]/number_of_makes)[1]" />

      <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $n">
        <xsl:element name="li">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(./car_make/price_per_make * ./car_make/number_of_makes, '0,000,000.00')"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="../continent/text()"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="../location/text()"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="../address/text()"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="./car_make/name/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="ContinentAverage">
  <xsl:param name="continentName" />
  <xsl:element name="li">
    <xsl:value-of select="$continentName"/>
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/factory/branch[./continent[text()=$continentName]]//batch/car_make/price_per_make/text()) div count(/factory/branch[./continent[text()=$continentName]]//batch/car_make/price_per_make), '###,###.00')"/>        
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (HTML Source)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</h1>
    <h2>1. Average Car Price Per Continent</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>North America - 21,666.67</li>
      <li>Europe - 46,600.00</li>
      <li>Asia - 18,000.00</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Total Per Batch (?)</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>1,400,000.00 - North America - detroit - 45 parklane - doge</li>
      <li>1,350,000.00 - North America - texas - 46 parkland way - hummer</li>
      <li>1,200,000.00 - Europe - england - 56 parklane - bentely</li>
      <li>1,200,000.00 - Europe - england - 56 parklane - ferrari</li>
      <li>0,920,000.00 - Asia - japan - 56 yorki avenue - mazda</li>
      <li>0,798,000.00 - Europe - germany - 675 berlin avenue - opel</li>
      <li>0,480,000.00 - Europe - germany - 675 berlin avenue - mercedes</li>
      <li>0,480,000.00 - Asia - korea - 12 yung  - toyota</li>
      <li>0,400,000.00 - Asia - india - 67 new delhi way - ford</li>
      <li>0,300,000.00 - Asia - india - 67 new delhi way - tata</li>
      <li>0,280,000.00 - North America - detroit - 45 parklane - cadillac</li>
      <li>0,252,000.00 - Asia - korea - 12 yung  - skyline</li>
      <li>0,240,000.00 - North America - usa - 671 fourth avenue - toyota</li>
      <li>0,200,000.00 - Europe - france - 671 paris - nissan</li>
      <li>0,200,000.00 - Asia - japan - 56 yorki avenue - hyundai</li>
      <li>0,050,000.00 - North America - usa - 671 fourth avenue - opel</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>3. Top 3 Most Expensive Batch(es)</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>1,400,000.00 - North America - detroit - 45 parklane - doge</li>
      <li>1,350,000.00 - North America - texas - 46 parkland way - hummer</li>
      <li>1,200,000.00 - Europe - england - 56 parklane - bentely</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
As per comments this is now updated to calculate parts 2 and 3 per BRANCH rather than per BATCH.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

  <xsl:variable name="title">Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="head">
        <xsl:element name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="body">
        <xsl:element name="h1">
          <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:call-template name="AverageCarPricePerContinent" />
        <xsl:call-template name="TotalPerBranch" />
        <xsl:call-template name="TopNMostExpensiveBranches">
          <xsl:with-param name="n" select="3" />
        </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/factory/branch">
    <xsl:call-template name="ContinentAverage">
      <xsl:with-param name="continentName" select="./continent/text()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="AverageCarPricePerContinent">
    <xsl:element name="h2">
      <xsl:text>1. Average Car Price Per Continent</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="ol">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/factory/branch[not(./continent=preceding-sibling::branch/continent)]" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="TotalPerBranch">
    <xsl:element name="h2">
      <xsl:text>2. Total Per Branch (&#x25bc;)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="ol">
      <xsl:call-template name="OutputBranchesDesc">
        <xsl:with-param name="branches" select="/factory/branch" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="TopNMostExpensiveBranches">
    <xsl:param name="n" />
    <xsl:element name="h2">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('3. Top ',$n,' Most Expensive Branch(es)')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="OutputBranchesDesc">
      <xsl:with-param name="branches" select="/factory/branch" />
      <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="ContinentAverage">
    <xsl:param name="continentName" />
    <xsl:element name="li">
      <xsl:value-of select="$continentName"/>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/factory/branch[./continent[text()=$continentName]]//batch/car_make/price_per_make/text()) div count(/factory/branch[./continent[text()=$continentName]]//batch/car_make/price_per_make), '###,###.00')"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="OutputBranchesDesc">
    <xsl:param name="branches" />
    <xsl:param name="n" select="count($branches)" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$branches and $n &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="i">
          <xsl:call-template name="getHighest">
            <xsl:with-param name="branches" select="$branches" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="branchValue">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetBranchValue">
            <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="$branches[position() = $i]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="li">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number($branchValue, '0,000,000.00')"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$branches[position() = $i]/continent/text()"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$branches[position() = $i]/location/text()"/>
          <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$branches[position() = $i]/address/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="OutputBranchesDesc">
          <xsl:with-param name="branches" select="($branches)[position() != $i]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name ="getHighest">
    <xsl:param name="branches" />
    <xsl:param name="highestValue" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="highestIndex" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="currentIndex" select="1" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$branches">

        <xsl:variable name="currentBranchValue">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetBranchValue">
            <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="$branches[position() = 1]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="highest">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$highestValue &gt; $currentBranchValue">
              <xsl:value-of select="$highestValue"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentBranchValue"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="newHighestIndex">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$highestValue &gt; $currentBranchValue">
              <xsl:value-of select="$highestIndex"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentIndex"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:call-template name="getHighest">
          <xsl:with-param name="branches" select="($branches)[position() &gt; 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="highestValue" select="$highest" />
          <xsl:with-param name="highestIndex" select="$newHighestIndex" />
          <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="$currentIndex + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$highestIndex"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetBranchValue">
    <xsl:param name="branch" />
    <xsl:param name="value" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="i" select="count($branch//batch)" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$i &gt; 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetBranchValue">
          <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="$branch" />
          <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i - 1" />
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value + (($branch//batch)[position() = $i]/car_make[1]/number_of_makes[1])[1] * (($branch//batch)[position() = $i]/car_make[1]/price_per_make[1])[1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Updated Output**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Troy's Stack Overflow XSLT Challenge</h1>
    <h2>1. Average Car Price Per Continent</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>North America - 21,666.67</li>
      <li>Europe - 46,600.00</li>
      <li>Asia - 18,000.00</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Total Per Branch (▼)</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>2,400,000.00 - Europe - england - 56 parklane</li>
      <li>1,680,000.00 - North America - detroit - 45 parklane</li>
      <li>1,630,000.00 - North America - texas - 46 parkland way</li>
      <li>1,278,000.00 - Europe - germany - 675 berlin avenue</li>
      <li>1,120,000.00 - Asia - japan - 56 yorki avenue</li>
      <li>0,732,000.00 - Asia - korea - 12 yung </li>
      <li>0,700,000.00 - Asia - india - 67 new delhi way</li>
      <li>0,290,000.00 - North America - usa - 671 fourth avenue</li>
      <li>0,200,000.00 - Europe - france - 671 paris</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>3. Top 3 Most Expensive Branch(es)</h2>
    <li>2,400,000.00 - Europe - england - 56 parklane</li>
    <li>1,680,000.00 - North America - detroit - 45 parklane</li>
    <li>1,630,000.00 - North America - texas - 46 parkland way</li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Done (I think) - please let me know if that matches what you were after?

Comment: yep,.atleast it does the top 3 most expensive,.

Comment: am trying to run the xslt but not running,.at all,..i reckon it needs some editing,.thanks for your time and effort,.much appreciated

Comment: Hey @troy, no worries.  FYI: looks like the first stylesheet tag had been lost in the formatting (i.e. I hadn't put enough spaces in front of it for it to be included in the code block). Should be OK now. This works with MS Visual Studio's parser using no special libraries, so should work elsewhere (I think).

Comment: @ john,..the totals should comprise both the batches,..like for instance,..in north america i should not have two totals from one branch like on texas,.we gotta add up the totals of the two batches in texas then display the results,.and so forth,..sorry about that

Comment: No worries; I'm out for the day but may get a chance to revisit this on Monday evening. . . To clarify, you want the batch total per branch?  Is that true for both questions 2 & 3, or just for one of them?

Comment: ,yep batch total per branch,.true for question 2 and 3,.i appreciate your effort in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of update; long day at work today then no luck figuring out a nice way to sort on call-template that's pure xslt 1.0. . . will come back to it soon.

Comment: ,.i tried too, many other ways,.but wasnt successful,.i think its too complicated,..and time consuming,.

Comment: Hey @troy, I've now updated it with an XSLT1 compliant sort on the batches - sorry for the delay; needed a bit of time to figure out the complex sort routine.  Not a beautiful solution but gets the job done.  (ps. scroll down for the new answer; I left the original answer there also should anyone want the less complicated version in future.